# How to get value from an input control on a View (MVC)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, viewbag

I'm working on small mvc application, and on one point I need a value from my Controller's Method,
and my plan is to store that value in a ViewBag and get it on a View, so I did next:

```
ViewBag.SuccessBody = "This is a test";
```

And on my Razor View what I did was next:

```
<input id="customInput" type="hidden" value='@(ViewBag.SuccessBody)' />
```

//For testing purpose I tried with example below also ..

```
<input id="customInputAgain" type="hidden" class="form-control" value="@(ViewBag.SuccessBody)">
```

And when View loads I tried to get a value so I wrote this:

```
 <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var customVal = $("#customInput").val();
            var customValAgain = $("#customInputAgain").val();

            alert(customVal);
            alert(customValAgain);

        });
</script>
```

I even tried adding a

```
alert(customVal.value);

alert(customValAgain.value);
```

But it is not working also, so looks like I am not retrieving values from my Controller/ViewBag that is reason
            why alert allways show empty space - nothing.

**EDIT :**

I am setting this ViewBag value on a Edit of my article, acttualy on a `[HttpPost] EDIT`, so when user clicks Save Changes `[HttpPost] EDIT` method is invoked and when data is probably inserted in a database I am setting ViewBag value and redirecting user to same [HttpGet] Edit method. Here is how that does looks:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ArticleEditViewModel model)
{
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //Rest of the code
                ViewBag.SuccessBody = "This is a test";
                return RedirectToAction("Edit/" + product.Id, "Article");
            }
            else
            {
              return View("NotFound");
            }
            return View(model);
}
```

As you can see guys I defined ViewBag but I can not get the value on a View which should be stored in a input control..

Maybe the issue is because I defined a ViewBag in a HttpPost Action method and not in 
HttpGet where from I'm "opening the view" ?

Comment: Have you viewed the source code to see if there is actually a value for that element when the page loads?

Comment: What does <div>@ViewBag.SuccessBody</div>` generate?

Comment: @StephenMuecke when I check on the source of the page it looks like this : `<input id="customInput" type="hidden" />` as you can see there is no `value='@(ViewBag.SuccessBody)' ` so that means actually that is null so it is not rendered?

Comment: @Roxy'Pro let's start from the beginning.. does the view that you're trying to alert the message on.... correspond to the action that contains `ViewBag.SuccessBody`?

Comment: You need to show your controller methods associated with this view.

Comment: @Roxy'Pro any reason as to why you are using parenthesis? Why not just `value="@ViewBag.SuccessBody"`?

Comment: Make Sure your ViewBag is in same controller Action Method. if you are using an action method say "testMethod" in a controller that contains ViewBag.SuccessBody, then it is available in your "testMethod" View only. And do it in [HttpGet] method, not in [HttpPost] action

Comment: @StephenMuecke  check for an edit mate

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid Tried without them also, but its the same, probably Im not getting value from a controller..

Comment: @Roxy'Pro you need to set the ViewBag value in the `HttpGet` method.. not the `HttpPost`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) as I prefer explicitly knowing what I'm targeting:

```
var customVal = $("#customInput").attr("value");
```

As for the server-side, make sure that `ViewBag.SuccessBody` is actually declared and returns something.

```
public ActionResult FooAction()
{
    ViewBag.SuccessBody = "This is a test";
    return View();
}
```

Also make sure that you're returning `ViewBag.SuccessBody` from the correct action method, to it's corresponding view.

**Update**

Based on your edit: you're redirecting to a different action (the Edit `[HttpGet]` one), so obviously `ViewBag.SuccessBody` is not defined there. Why not just pass a `bool? editSuccess` parameter to your `[HttpGet]` Edit method, indicating whether the edit was successful or not?

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, bool? editSuccess)
{
    if (editSuccess.HasValue) 
    {
         if (editSuccess)
         {
             // edit was successful here
            ViewBag.SuccessBody = "Yay! :)";
         }
         else
         {
            // edit was unsuccessful here
            ViewBag.SuccessBody = "No! :(";
         }
    } 
    // other stuff
    return View();
}
```

Your `[HttpPost]` action then becomes:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ArticleEditViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // ...
        RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = product.Id, editSuccess = true });
    }
    else
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Using this approach you can specify when the edit might have failed as well, by setting `editSuccess` to `false`. If you're simply interested in passing whatever value back to the view, then skip all the `editSuccess` parts and simply return `ViewBag.SuccessBody` from the `[HttpGet]` action, instead of the `[HttpPost]` one.

Aside: Obviously, as `editSuccess` is optional and you're only setting `ViewBag.SuccessBody` to something when `editSuccess` actually has a value, you can do this check in the view to determine whether to output something or not in the HTML:

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.SuccessBody)) 
{ 
    // not empty, do something
}
```

Comment: Not saying that this is wrong, but `val` should be working, which leads me to think that something else is wrong other than the jQuery methods he/she is using.

Comment: Yeah you're probably right, I've just read the discussion with @Stephen Muecke in the OP.

Comment: @trashr0x check for my Edit mate, looks like it's issue in a controller and not in a view/javascript, looks like I'm not getting the value from my ViewBag which is defined in a controller.

Answer (score 1):

You Can use tempdata for this

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(ArticleEditViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Rest of the code
            TempData["SuccessBody"] = "This is a test"; ;
            return RedirectToAction("Edit/" + product.Id, "Article");


        }
        else
        {
            return View("NotFound");
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

And in your get Method use this

```
if (TempData["SuccessBody"] != null && TempData.ContainsKey("SuccessBody"))
                ViewBag.SuccessBody = Convert.ToString(TempData["SuccessBody"]);
```

Comment: Refer this, it will help you to understand about ViewBag,ViewData,TempData
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/viewdata-vs-viewbag-vs-tempdata-in-mvc1